# Vitis HLS Pointer to Pointer is not supported for variable when initializing struct array

Tags: c, fpga, xilinx, register-transfer-level, vivado-hls

I'm trying to make a state machine that is synthesizable into a hardware description through Vitis HLS. I'm getting the error `ERROR: [HLS 214-134] in function 'kernel1(char*, int)': Pointer to pointer is not supported for variable ''`. This is happening in:

- `Transition transitions[] = {a, b};`, where I'm trying to create an array of `Transition` structs
- `transitions_occurred += testTransition(&transitions[i], stream, &stream_index);`, where I'm trying to call a function with members of the previous array

I don't get why that specific error pops up in these situations. I get no error when trying to do it 'manually' (without the array), like in:

```
transitions_occurred += testTransition(&a, stream, &stream_index);
transitions_occurred += testTransition(&b, stream, &stream_index);
```

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    bool active;
} State;

typedef struct {
    char token;
    State *current;
    State *next;
    int stream_increment;
} Transition;

bool testTransition(Transition *t, char* stream, int *stream_index)
{
    if (!t->current->active)
        return false;
    
    if (t->token == stream[*stream_index])
    {
        t->next->active = true;
        *stream_index += t->stream_increment;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

#define STATE_NO 3
#define START_STATE 0
#define END_STATE 2

bool kernel1(char stream[], int stream_size)
{
    State current[STATE_NO] = {0};
    State next[STATE_NO] = {0};
    current[START_STATE].active = true;

    Transition a = {'a', &current[0], &next[1], 1};
    Transition b = {'b', &current[1], &next[2], 1};
    Transition transitions[] = {a, b};
    size_t transition_no = sizeof(transitions) / sizeof(Transition);

    int stream_index = 0;
    int transitions_occurred;

    do {
        transitions_occurred = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < transition_no; i++)
            transitions_occurred += testTransition(&transitions[i], stream, &stream_index);

        memcpy(current, next, STATE_NO * sizeof(State));
        memset(next, 0, STATE_NO * sizeof(State));
    } while (stream_index != stream_size && transitions_occurred);

    return current[END_STATE].active;
}
```

Comment: What version of C used to compile?

Comment: Where can I see that? I'm new to Vitis HLS

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've tried running it with `-std=c99/11/14/17` in the `CFLAGS` and the error persists

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar enough then for Vitis HLS.  Good luck.

Comment: Minor: `for (int i = 0; i < transition_no; i++)` better as `for (size_t i = 0; i < transition_no; i++)`.  No need to mix types.  (Tip: enable more warnings.)

Comment: _"It has to do with the notion that in HLS, C is being used to define hardware, not write software. So HLS must know the size at compile time, which it cannot do here. You might be able to get away with a char x[ARRAY_LEN] array in the struct, but you would have to try it and see."_ - [Why Pointer to pointer is not supported?](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006q0lKVSAY/why-pointer-to-pointer-is-not-supported?language=en_US)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Isn't the size of `Transition` fixed? How can `Transition transitions[2]`'s size not be known then?

Comment: @136 Yes, the size of `transitions` is known at compile time but if I understand it correctly, the contained pointers is what makes the hardware definition tricky for HLS. It seems they use C for a different purpose than writing software. If noone here on SO is familiar with HLS, I suggest seeking help at their forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't get why that specific error pops up in these situations.

`transitions` is a pointer to `Transition` objects which contain pointers.

> I get no error when trying to do it 'manually' (without the array)

Vivado-HLS will inline function calls with pointer-to-pointer. That is why a direct call with the reference to the object works as no pointer to that object is ever created.

Pointer to pointer support is limited. Please check the Pointer sections in the user guides [UG902](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ug902-vivado-high-level-synthesis) / [UG1399](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1399-vitis-hls/Pointers).